# Why are month and date in wrong position for date('Y-m-d') in PHP?

Tags: php

The timezone on my server is correct, but the month and day being returned by date() are not in the position I expect.

```
vdump(date_default_timezone_get());

string(19) "America/Los_Angeles"

vdump($_SESSION['StartDate']);

string(10) "11-10-2013"  //Nov 10
```

I then want to convert that string to a date, so I do:

```
vdump(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_SESSION['StartDate'])));

string(10) "2013-10-11"
```

Which is Oct 11 ???

But when I do the same with 'today', it's the format I expect:

```
vdump(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('today')));

string(10) "2013-11-18"  //Nov 18
```

So, how do I get the day and month in the correct positions for the date stored in $_SESSION?  And why am I seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/strtotime#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

You're using dashes, so it's assuming European d-m-y for "11-10-2013" which is Oct 11.